# Facebook logging into wrong app on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication

My iOS app uses Facebook for logging in, however my dev team recently decided to consolidate all our apps into one universal Facebook app with a common APP ID.  So I went into my project and tried to change my FacebookAppID and URL Types to the right APP ID, but when I run the app and click on the login button, it redirects me to log into my old app on Facebook.  I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, but here is what I have in my AppDelegate file:

```
/*
 Callback for session changes
*/
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session found");
        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    }
}

/*
 * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
 */
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        @"user_games_activity",
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
}

/*
 * If we have a valid session at the time of openURL call, we handle
 * Facebook transitions by passing the url argument to handleOpenURL
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
/*
 *Logout
 *
 */
- (void) closeSession {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have two applications on your device that have the same Facebook URL scheme in the application Info.plist. You can either:

- Remove the old app, or
- Reinstall the old app but remove the Facebook URL scheme from the Info.plist file beforehand

You may have more than one URL scheme. If so, you should look for the one that looks like fbxxxxxxxxxxx, which is displayed on your app page on http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Turns out I had more than one URL scheme, fixed the problem right up! Thanks much.

Comment: I found that the two apps i have have the same facebook URL scheme and  I changed The url scheme but nothing happend, still open another application.

Answer (score 0):

we can still use same facebook url scheme in different application using UrlSchemeSuffix.
for that we can set [image: facebook developer console]

Then inside Info.plist file:

```
<key>FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix</key>
<string>$(FACEBOOK_URL_ENV)</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
</array>
```

setup your custom variables XCode:
Build Settings > User defined (add new user defined setting)

(replace your facebook app id after fbXXXXXXXXXXXXsuffixValue)

[image]